# Vue Iteration inside element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am attempting to iterate through an array from a Vue component **without** reapeating the element on which I call 'v-for'. I have not found a subsitute for 'v-for' in the [official docs API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/), nor in [articles](https://alligator.io/vuejs/iterating-v-for/) online.

I have this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <foo :index="index">
  <foo/>
</div>
```

Want this:

```
<foo :index="0"><foo/> 

<foo :index="1"><foo/>

<foo :index="2"><foo/>
//etc...
```

And have tried this, which does not work:

```
<foo v-for="(item, index) in items":index="index">
<foo/>
```

Help is much appreciated! Started coding with Vue.js yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is wrong. You can do this just fine.

```
<foo v-for="(item, index) in items" :index="index"></foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<foo v-for="(item, index) in items">
    {{index}}
</foo>
```

Comment: I have edited the question. I need to be able to use index in a foo attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you http://jsbin.com/kapipezalu/edit?html,js,console,output

You probably forgot to define props into foo component.

```
  <div id="app">
    <foo v-for="(item, index) in items" :index="index"></foo>
  </div>

  <template id="foo-temp">
    <div>
      <span>{{ index }}</span>
    </div>
  </template>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('foo', {
  props: ['index'],
  template: '#foo-temp'
})

new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    items: [
      {id: 1, title: 'One'},
      {id: 2, title: 'Two'},
      {id: 3, title: 'Three'}
    ]
  }

})
```

> **Pro Tip:** Use Browser Console - It will show you some cool warnings and errors.